# JS insertHtml without focus?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some code written in PHP with textarea input field. I also have a JS code that inserts html code into field:

```
$('form textarea#response').ready(function() {

    function populateGet() {
        var obj = {}, params = location.search.slice(1).split('&');
        for(var i=0, len=params.length;i<len;i++) {
            var keyVal = params[i].split('=');
            obj[decodeURIComponent(keyVal[0])] = decodeURIComponent(keyVal[1]);
        }
        return obj;
    }
    var test = populateGet();
    var ticid;
    for(var key in test) {
        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(test, key)) {
            var val = test[key];
            ticid = val;
        }
    }

    $('form select#cannedResp').val('original');

    var fObj = $(this).closest('form');
    var    $url =  'ajax.php/tickets/'+ticid+'/canned-resp/original.json';
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $url,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(canned){
            console.log('dupa');
                //Canned response.
                var box = $('form textarea#response'),
                    redactor = box.data('redactor');
                if(canned.response) {
                    if (redactor){
                        redactor.insertHtml(canned.response);
                    }else{
                        box.val(box.val() + canned.response);
                box.blur();
            }
                    //if (redactor)
                        //redactor.observeStart();
                }
                //Canned attachments.
                var ca = $('.attachments', fObj);
                if(canned.files && ca.length) {
                    var fdb = ca.find('.dropzone').data('dropbox');
                    $.each(canned.files,function(i, j) {
                      fdb.addNode(j);
                    });
                }
            document.getElementById('focustest').focus();
            }
        })
        .done(function() { })
        .fail(function() { });

});
```

The problem is that execution of above code (redactor.insertHtml(canned.response);) causes focus on the textarea. The code is executed on page load.

Is there any way I can insert the content into field without causing the focus to placed on this field?

Thank you in advance and best regards
Tom

Comment: how about calling blur function on that field after inserting the content?